# Maintain pthread after executing

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

Is it possible to have a POSIX thread remain "alive" after executing the function given as an argument? As in reusing that thread for further work.

For example, given a queue of functions to execute, is it possible to have a pthread execute several of them? The alternative would be creating a pthread for every task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.

What you describe reminds me of a *thread pool*, where a set of threads is waiting for work (your functions in this case) to execute.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did some quick research on thread pools and it appears to be exactly what I need. I'm probably missing something here, but how does keeping threads in a pool (however that might be implemented) differ from the concept present in my question of maintaining a certain amount of threads to execute more than one function?

Comment: @SaucyGoat that's not parallel execution. You just have one slave pick all the rocks to build the Pyramid. So, until he does the round trip, the rocks are stockpiled. Now, if you have many slaves, the rocks can reach the pyramid much sooner! ;)